# onClick javascript changes are not reflected without reloading page

Tags: javascript, html, dom, layout

I have a `<select> <option></option </select>` to represent the start and end date of outage report called Outage Start Data and Outage End Date respectively. Also, I have a text field to enter numeric values for an outage report called Amount.
Note: Options were created by Perl script.

Here for both text field and start and end date field, I have a separate `reset` and `clear` anchor tag. when clicking `reset` for the start or end date it will set the current date to the respective field(start or end) and for the Amount field, it will set to value `150`. When clicking `clear` it will clear the respective fields.

Now my problem is the `rest` and `clear` for the Amount field is working fine. And for both start and end date the pointer is pointing to the desired index in options(say for clear it is pointing to empty option and for reset its pointing to the current date, month, year), but this is not reflecting in my webpage without reloading the page(but this is also not working with chrome).

I want to make it work like for the Amount field.

```
/*
Start Date snippet is the same for month and year
*/
<lable>Outage Start Date</lable>

<select>
for(sort keys $startDateSet) {
  if($_ eq lstStartDate) {
       $sel = "selected";
   }
   else {
       $sel = "";
   }
print "<option". $sel. "value=".$startDateSet[$_]."</option>
  }
</select>

<a id="lstStartDate" href="javascript:clearOutageStartDate();">clear</a>
<a id="lstStartDate" href="javascript:restOutageStartDate();">reset</a>

/* 
Same for the end date 
*/
function clearOutageStartDate() {
    document.outage_report.lstStartDate.selectedIndex = -1;
    document.outage_report.lstStartMonth.selectedIndex = -1;
    document.outage_report.lstStartYear.selectedIndex = -1;
}
```

```
/*
Same for the end date
*/
function resetOutageStartDate(month, date, year) {
    document.outage_report.lstStartDate.value = date;
    document.outage_report.lstStartMonth.value = month;
    document.outage_report.lstStartYear.value = year;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide enough html to reproduce your issue as per [mcve]

Comment: Is your anchor tag inside a button? Can we see your HTML code?

Comment: Its a .cgi file. I have added the perl code snippet which creates option for start date, that is same for month and year

Comment: What will be the problem?? The same is working fine for Text Fields

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the select options to match the value to set the index.

```
var el = document.getElementById("lstStartYear");
for (i=0;i<el.size;i++) {
 if (el.option[i].value==year) { el.selectedIndex=i; }}
```

To clear you should be using

```
document.getElementById("lstStartYear").selectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: But we can use ```document.getElementById("lstStartDate").value = date```also to set the index right??

Comment: No, value is not a attribute of the select element.

Comment: I think it did work in Internet Explorer but unlikely in others.

Comment: As I mentioned, the pointer is pointing to the correct index but its not reflected in the page. Means after clicking reset when I click the dropdown it selected the desired index value but the selected value is not reflected in the page. While debugging the JS changes were happened correctly. But my problem is it doesnt reflected.